# Change the value in my properties file with <replaceregexp>

Tags: ant

I have a properties file:

**custom.properties**

the content of this properties file is:

```
id=sf2j2345kkklljhlaasfsdfafsf543
name = SOME_NAME
```

I'd like to change the value of the id to "**aaa**", that's change the content of the file to:

```
id=aaa
name = SOME_NAME
```

I tried:

```
 <target name="change-id">  
        <replaceregexp file="custom.properties" match="^id=.*" replace="id=aaa" encoding="UTF-8" />
 </target>
```

I run command `ant change-id`

The build is successful, **But it does not work**, the content of my properties file is **unchanged**. **Why?**

Comment: Looks fine by me. Are you sure your file is found by ant?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, since I have use the same file path for other target,which is working fine.

Comment: Try to give absolute path and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

For editing propertyfiles use the [Propertyfile Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html)
f.e. :

```
<propertyfile file="some.properties">
  <entry  key="id" value="aaa"/>
</propertyfile>
```

Comment: I do not want to use PropertyFile because I want to only use Ant core component. The PropertyFile is from the ant optional package

Comment: Both PropertyFile Task and ReplaceRegexp Task are in the optional taskdef package :-))) Optional tasks usually have library dependencies as f.e. junit, ssh .. etc. but PropertyFile has no dependencies. Before ant 1.8 the optional taskdef package was in ant-nodeps.jar, now it is in ant.jar